# animation a bar around a rounded button

Tags: css

I am trying to achieve a thing that when a button is pressed a bar around the button should be animated.

This is my button css

```css
button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 22px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  background: #2196F3;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-50%);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(25, 25);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(40, 40);
  }
}

button:focus:not(:active)::after {
  animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button>
+
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k1a3ha4c/2/

I am not able to think the logic in CSS3 how to create a loading bar around a button. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a pseudo before element and then follow the [w3schools guide](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_loader.asp) on how to make a loader.

The example I provide creates a pseudo `::before` element which has a 1/4 round green border, when the button is clicked the spin animation is called which spins the element with an ease-in-out effect.
`animation: spin 1s cubic-bezier(0.46, 0.03, 0.52, 0.96) 1;`

**Example:**

```css
button {
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 22px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  background: #2196F3;
  outline: none;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  // overflow: hidden;
}

button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  top: -5px;
  left: -5px;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  border-top: 5px solid #008744;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
}

button:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(1, 1) translate(-50%);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes ripple {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(15, 15);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(20, 20);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

button:focus:not(:active)::before {
  animation: ripple 1s ease-out;
}

button:focus:not(:active)::after {
  animation: spin 1s cubic-bezier(0.46, 0.03, 0.52, 0.96) 1;
}
```

```html
<button>
+
</button>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is what I wanted but can it have just one iteration and not inside button but outside. like on border.?

Comment: Check my updated answer it should now work as you say, hope this is now an acceptable answer.